# Can you help me solving this limit

Tags: real-analysis

Can you help me solving this limit?

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\right)^{1/n}
$$

Comment: You should format the question appropriately

Comment: I am new can you help me

Comment: I tried to format but it was not clear what you were asking so make sure that is correct

Comment: @SeadMejzini Read the directions in this site to format correctly mathematics

Comment: Also, what have you tried? E.g. Stirling approximation?!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that does not rely on Stirling's Formula, but rather uses Riemann sums.  To that end, we proceed.

First note that we can write the limit of interest as

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{\frac1n \left(3\log(n!)-\log((3n)!)\right)} \tag 1$$

Second, we write the exponent on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac1n \left(3\log(n!)-\log((3n)!)\right)&=\frac1n \left(3\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)-\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log(k)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1n\left(3\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)-\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log(k/n)\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Third, we note that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is simply the Riemann sum

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\left(3\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)-\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log(k/n)\right) &=3\int_0^1 \log(x)\,dx-\int_0^3 \log(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\log(27) \tag 3
\end{align}$$

Finally, using $(3)$ in $(1)$ we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{27}}$$

Comment: Good alternative.  (+1) I can never remember Stirling's formula.

Comment: @RRL Thanks!  Yours was much more efficient.  Although I do remember Stirling's Formula (SF), it is sometimes used unnecessarily.  Also, I believe that Riemann sums are more basic (i.e., introduced earlier) and thus more appropriate for addressing certain questions.  Have a great weekend!  -Mark

Comment: This is freaking beautiful. +1

Comment: @joanpemo Wow!  Thank you.

Comment: @Dr.MV No, thank you. In fact the step that almost made me faint is (2): to substract and then add $\;\log n\;$ is really ingenous.

Comment: @Joanpemo Joan, I'm glad that you only "almost" fainted and didn't actually faint.  ;-)) -Mark

Answer (score 3):

Aapply Cauchy's limit theorem

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},$$

with

$$a_n = \frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}.$$

Then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{((n+1)!)^3 (3n)!}{(3n+3)!(n!)^3} = \frac{(n+1)^3}{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)} \to \frac{1}{27}$$

Comment: This is efficient!  +1 I posted another solution that circumvented use of Stirling's Formula and relies only on Riemann sums.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Using [Stirling's Approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\left(\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\right)^{1/n}\sim\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)^3\left(\frac ne\right)^{3n}}{\sqrt{6\pi n}\left(\frac{3n}e\right)^{3n}}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{3\pi n}}{2^{1/n}}\cdot\frac1{3^3}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1{27}$$

Answer (score 0):

The help/hint is to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

and evaluate.

Along the way you will also need $\lim Cn^{1/n} = 1$.

You will end up with $\frac{1}{27}$ if I'm not mistaken.